# Why Bloomberg USD swap curve (YCSW0023 Index) changes last month?? and why put a Financial commodity future into this curve?

Tags: swaps, bloomberg, discounting

The Bloomberg USD swap curve (YCSW0023 Index) had changed and bloomberg put a Financial commodity future.

Why changes? What the factor make this changes? Why bloomberg put into a financial commodity future.

[image]

*This is not the complete curve...

Comment: Would not it be more efficient to ask Bloomberg support (F1 F1)?

Comment: ED are Eurodollar futures as you probably know. They can be used as estimators of future 3-mo Libors in the short/medium term.

Comment: maybe this instruments can be moore liquid!

Answer (score 1):

Really a question for the help desk `F1 F1`.

However, that is not a recent change. `ICVS 23` uses these since years. If you did not have that, I suspect you restored `SWDF DFLT` in which case you see what is recommended.

Ignore the classification - it's not a commodity - it's ED future. `HELP ICVS` has white papers. The first one, `Building the BBG IR Curve` discusses this in quite some detail.